# Filter out friends that have already approved the app from app invite dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

In old Facebook sdk(using `FBWebDialogs`) I was able to set filters and exclude friends with approved app to be listed for invites. Now(with `FBSDKAppInviteDialog`) I can't find the way to enable such filters.
Is there any way to get old functionality back?

Comment: I don’t think you need to filter that yourself any more, but rather FB will do it automatically for you – they added `FBSDKGameRequestDialog` to send “normal” requests that are not invites, so I’d expect `FBSDKAppInviteDialog` to only show users that are not using the app yet.

Comment: I have tested it out and list of friends to invite contains friends that already have approved app. And I am using `FBSDKAppInviteDialog `.

Comment: Is your app a canvas app? then you might want to look at invitable friends. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.3

Comment: @lamdadj22 This works only for games.